# How to count moved files with bash script?

Tags: bash

My bash script moves screenshot files from desktop into newly created folder.
I would like it to echo the number of the files moved after it finishes.

I've tried with exit code, but it only shows an exit code for one command which is mv.
Is there a way that I can see what is going under the hood of mv command, which in that case moves more than one file?

```sh
#!/bin/bash
date=$(date +"%d-%m-%y")
mkdir SCREENS/"$date"
mv Screenshot*.png SCREENS/"$date"
#echo $? - it gives only one exit code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Use the `for`, look:*

```
$ c=0 ; for f in *.png ; do mv "$f" destination/ && ((c++)) ; done ; echo $c
2
```

Comment: `do mv "$f" destination/ && ((i++))` should be the right way I guess. Only increment `i` if mv was successful

Comment: @WalterA And yet another inch further. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are moving to a new directory, so you can count the files in the new directory.
A filename can have a newline, so a simple `wc` will fail (don't parse `ls`).
You can instruct `find` to write one line for each file and count those lines:

```
find SCREENS/"$date" -type f -exec echo x \; | wc -l
```